# IndexError: Peng Robinson equation code for multiple components

Tags: python, arrays

I have the following code:

```
from scipy.constants import R as Rgi
from numpy import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

## Constants

```
Tccomp = array([190.56,305.32,369.83,425.12,469.7,507.6,282.34,365.57,511.76,553.58,562.16,591.8,512.64,513.92,536.78,400.1,408.00,508.2,591.95,469.15,132.45,154.58,126.2,405.65,430.75,304.26,647.13,535.5]) #k
Pccomp = array([45.90,48.50,42.10,37.70,33.60,30.40,50.30,46.30,45.00,41.00,48.00,41.30,81.40,61.20,51.20,52.70,65.90,47.10,57.40,72.60,37.90,50.20,33.98,113.00,78.60,73.90,219.40,41.50]) # bar
Vccomp = array([0.099,0.146,0.2,0.255,0.315,0.373,0.132,0.188,0.257,0.308,0.261,0.314,0.117,0.168,0.22,0.171,0.115,0.21,0.179,0.142,0.092,0.074,0.089,0.072,0.123,0.095,0.056,0.267]) # m^3/kmol
Zccomp = array([0.286,0.279,0.273,0.272,0.271,0.269,0.283,0.286,0.272,0.274,0.273,0.262,0.224,0.24,0.252,0.271,0.223,0.234,0.208,0.264,0.318,0.287,0.288,0.241,0.269,0.277,0.228,0.249])
Wcomp = array([0.011,0.098,0.149,0.197,0.251,0.304,0.086,0.137,0.196,0.212,0.209,0.262,0.566,0.643,0.617,0.192,0.282,0.307,0.463,0.201,0.0,0.02,0.037,0.253,0.244,0.244,0.343,0.323])
Nombre = array(['Metano','Etano','Propano','Butano','Pentano','Hexano','Etileno','Propileno','Ciclopentano','Ciclohexano','Benceno','Tolueno','Metanol','Etanol','1-Propanol','Dimetileter','Formaldehido','Acetona','Acido Actico','Oxido de etileno','Aire','Oxigeno','Nitrogeno','Amoniaco','Dioxido de azufre','Dioxido de carbono','Agua','Metiletilcetona'])
Rbar = Rgi*10 # bar*cm^3/K*mol
Rgas = Rgi # Kj / Kmol * K
```

## Program interface

```
print 'Cálculo de la fugacidad de una mezcla de gases reales utilizando Peng Robinson'
print '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
print ' Metano                          |(0)| '
print ' Etano                           |(1)| '
print ' Propano                         |(2)| '
print ' Butano                          |(3)| '
print ' Pentano                         |(4)| '
print ' Hexano                          |(5)| '
print ' Etileno                         |(6)| '
print ' Propileno                       |(7)| '
print ' Ciclopentano                    |(8)| '
print ' Ciclohexano                     |(9)| '
print ' Benceno                         |(10)|'
print ' Tolueno                         |(11)|'
print ' Metanol                         |(12)|'
print ' Etanol                          |(13)|'
print ' 1-propanol                      |(14)|'
print ' Dimetileter                     |(15)|'
print ' Formaldehido                    |(16)|'
print ' Acetona                         |(17)|'
print ' Ácido acético                   |(18)|'
print ' Óxido de etileno                |(19)|'
print ' Aire                            |(20)|'
print ' Oxígeno                         |(21)|'
print ' Nitrógeno                       |(22)|'
print ' Amoniaco                        |(23)|'
print ' Dióxido de azufre               |(24)|'
print ' Agua                            |(25)|'
print ' Metiletilcetona                 |(26)|'
print '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
print ' '
print ' '

ncomp = int(input('numero de componentes del sistema  : '))

def PRMix(T,P):

    comp = zeros(ncomp)
    y = zeros(ncomp)
    Wcomp =  zeros(ncomp)
    Tccomp = zeros(ncomp)
    Pccomp = zeros(ncomp)
    a = zeros(ncomp)
    b = zeros(ncomp)
    sumbi = zeros(ncomp)
    s = (ncomp,ncomp)
    aij = zeros(s)
    sumaij = zeros(s)

    for i in arange(0,ncomp,1):
        comp[i] = int(input('Escoja el componente : '))
        y[i] = float(input(' Fraccion : '))
        print '      '

    for i in arange (0,ncomp,1):
        Wcomp[i] = Wcomp[int(comp[i])]
        Tccomp[i] = Tccomp[int(comp[i])]
        Pccomp[i] = Pccomp[int(comp[i])]


    kappa = 0.37464 + 1.54226*Wcomp - 0.26992*Wcomp**2
    alpha = (1 + kappa*(1 - sqrt(T/Tccomp)))**2
    a     = 0.45724*(((Rgi**2) * (Tccomp**2))/(Pccomp))*alpha
    b     = 0.0788*((Rgi*Tccomp)/Pccomp)
    for i in arange(0,ncomp,1):
        sumbi[i] = y[i]*b[i]
        for j in arange(0,ncomp,1):
            aij[i,j] = sqrt(a[i]*a[j])
            sumaij[i,j] = y[i]*y[j] * aij[i,j]
    amix = sum(sumaij)
    bmix = sum(sumbi)

    Aij = (aij * P) / ((Rgi*T)**2)
    Bi = (b * P) / (Rgi * T)
    Amix = (amix * P)/((Rgi*T)**2)
    Bmix = (bmix * P)/(Rgi * T)

    pol = [1,(Bmix - 1), (Amix - 2 * Bmix - 3 * Bmix**2),(Bmix**2 + Bmix**3 -Amix * Bmix)]
    Z = roots(pol)
    Z = real(Z)
    Zvmix = max(Z)
    Zlmix = min(Z)


    LnPhiV = (Bi/Bmix)*(Zvmix-1) - log(Zvmix-Bmix)-(Amix/(2*Sqrt(2)*Bmix)) * ((2 *(dot(Aij,y)/Amix) -(Bi/Bmix)) * log((Zvmix + (1 + sqrt(2)) * Bmix) / (Zvmix + (1 - sqrt(2)) * Bmix)))

    LnPhiL = (Bi/Bmix)*(Zlmix-1) - log(Zlmix-Bmix)-(Amix/(2*Sqrt(2)*Bmix)) * ((2 *(dot(Aij,y)/Amix) -(Bi/Bmix)) * log((Zlmix + (1 + sqrt(2)) * Bmix) / (Zlmix + (1 - sqrt(2)) * Bmix)))

    PhiV = exp(LnPhiV)
    PhiL = exp(LnPhiL)
```

However, when I run it I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 82, in PRMix
    Wcomp[i] = Wcomp[int(comp[i])]
IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
>>> IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

I can't figure out what's wrong. I tried reading about the error but didn't find anything that applied to my code.

Comment: Hi. To improve your chances of getting an answer, please post a minimal *self-contained* piece of code - see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Additionally, replace the "input" statements (with constants for example) so that those who want to reproduce your error can just run the code, and don't have to type anything.